# send PDF attachment in email using grails mail plugin

Tags: grails, pdf, groovy, rendering, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to send a PDF file as an attachment in an email. I don't want to save pdf file on server or client machine. I've tried following. But it doesn't work. Please suggest correct way to do it.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "path to template", model: [account:account])

asynchronousMailService.sendMail {
                    multipart true
                    to emailID
                    subject emailSubject
                    html emailBodyContent
                    attachBytes "filename.pdf", "application/pdf", bytes
                }
```

it doesn't work as it requires byte to send in attachment. And `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't give output in bytes. Does anyone has solution for this ?

I tried `bytes.toByteArray()`. But it gave following exception :

```
2014-11-03/22:25:35.994 [http-bio-8080-exec-9]  ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /morningProc/approvalPdfFR
No signature of method: [B.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [B) values: [Approval.pdf, application/pdf, [37, 80, ...]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), grep(), dump(), find(), collect(). Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [B.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [B) values: [Approval.pdf, application/pdf, [37, 80, ...]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), grep(), dump(), find(), collect()
    at com.crm.MultilingualEmailService$_$tt__sendEmailFormateWithAttachment_closure14$$EOuZNrCU.doCall(MultilingualEmailService.groovy:79)
    at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:39)
    at MailGrailsPlugin$_configureSendMail_closure7.doCall(MailGrailsPlugin.groovy:180)
    at com.crm.MultilingualEmailService$$EOuZNrCS.$tt__sendEmailFormateWithAttachment(MultilingualEmailService.groovy:74)
    at com.crm.MorningProcController$$EOuZVK1N.approvalPdfFR(MorningProcController.groovy:882)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Even I tried using Wkhtmltopdf plugin. but it gave error.
I tried following code:

```
byte[] pdfData = wkhtmltoxService.makePdf(
            view: "/morningProc/approvalPdfFR",
            model: [account:accountInst],
            header: "",
            footer: "",
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: 35,
            marginBottom: 20,
            marginRight: 20,
            headerSpacing: 10
    )
```

But unfortunately no luck. It throws exception :

```
Cannot find wkhtml executable at [:] trying to make it available with the makeBinaryAvailableClosure
2014-11-04/00:50:35.985 [http-bio-8080-exec-2]  ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - GroovyCastException occurred when processing request: [GET] /morningProc/approvalPdfFR
Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.ConfigObject@5ee8e41c' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'groovy.lang.Closure' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: failed to invoke constructor: public groovy.lang.Closure(java.lang.Object) with arguments: [[:]] reason: java.lang.InstantiationException. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.ConfigObject@5ee8e41c' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'groovy.lang.Closure' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: failed to invoke constructor: public groovy.lang.Closure(java.lang.Object) with arguments: [[:]] reason: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.wkhtmltox.WkhtmltoxService.makePdf(WkhtmltoxService.groovy:56)
    at org.wkhtmltox.WkhtmltoxService.makePdf(WkhtmltoxService.groovy:35)
    at com.crm.MorningProcController$$EOua5loZ.approvalPdfFR(MorningProcController.groovy:881)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Try `bytes.toByteArray();`

Comment: @Jens : it doesn't work. Please see my updated question.

Comment: does `attachBytes 'filename.pdf', 'application/pdf", bytes` work?  are you using the `Asynchronous Mail Plugin 1.1` plugin?

Comment: @cfrick: yupp it worked.. I did clean and refresh dependencies.

Comment: so what fixed it?  not using `"` or just the cleanup?

Comment: @cfrick : i'm using asynchronous-mail:1.0 plugin. I've updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked for me. Following is the solution :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "path to template", model: [account:account])

asynchronousMailService.sendMail {
                    multipart true
                    to emailID
                    subject emailSubject
                    html emailBodyContent
                    attachBytes "filename.pdf", "application/pdf", bytes.toByteArray()
                }
```

And also I did run clean up command. Also there is one tip, don't put the variable name of bytes as 'attachBytes'. Like : `attachBytes "filename.pdf", "application/pdf", attachBytes.toByteArray()` 
It also caused me so much time to come to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via Grails Mail Plugin:

> Note: Before using the below code snippet. You should have already
> configured the grails mail plugin in your Config.groovy file.

Use the following code snippet in you controller or service and then modify it as per your requirements:

```
def EmailSendingWithPDF {

    sendMail { 

        multipart true // For attaching multiple files
        from "example@example.com"
        to "Sending_Email_address"
        bcc "example@example.com"
        subject "Your Subject Here"
        html params.anyText
        
        // An Example of automatic attachment with Image:
        def logo_Example = Domain_Name.findById(id_number)
        byte[] logoAttached = logo_Example?.myFile
        inline 'logo', 'image/png', logoAttached
        
        // An Example of automatic attachment with PDF:
        def pdfFile
        byte[] attachedPdf = pdfFile?.myFile
        attach pdfFile.name, "application/pdf", attachedPdf

    }

}
```